# Are my Function Apps dependent on Storage Accounts? I want to move my Function Apps to a new Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Goal: Move all the necessary, and only the necessary, function apps and their dependencies from one resource group to another. This resource group they are currently in contains an App Configuration, 2 App Services (Function Apps), their Application Insights, a Storage account, and an App Service Plan.

The resource group I want to move them into already has things like Storage accounts, other Function apps, Logic apps, etc.

I have tried consulting the docs, maybe I am consulting the wrong ones. I am still puzzled about the dependencies Function Apps may have, and why this resource group needed to spin up a Storage account and what azure-webjobs-host and what the files populating within it mean or do.

**Q1**: How can I move them to the new resource group? I am thinking of using their ARM templates, but am vague on details.

**Q2**: Do I need to bring their Storage account with them?

**Q3**: Could I instead integrate them with the Storage account in their new resource group, after I moved them? How?

**Q4**: Can I simply delete Function Apps' Application Insights if I have no further use for them?

**Q5**: Any good resources or knowledge you want to share about Logic Apps / Function Apps being dependent on other resource types?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are my Function Apps dependent on Storage Accounts?

Yes, function app on azure needs you to specified a storage account. This is because triggers other than httptrigger needs storage emulator.(This is built-in feature.)

> How can I move them to the new resource group?

If you dont have too many function apps to move, just click 'Move' -> 'Move to another resource group' in the overview of your resource group and then select the function app you want to move.

[image]

[image]

> Do I need to bring their Storage account with them?

No. No matter built-in feature or your function app need to deal with some storage accounts, it just needs you to offer connection string to link to.

> Could I instead integrate them with the Storage account in their new
> resource group, after I moved them? How?

Yes.(If you are talking about built-in feature.) But you need to change this value:

[image]

And the value is getting from this place:

[image]

> Can I simply delete Function Apps' Application Insights if I have no
> further use for them?

Yes, you can. It is just a way to monitor your function app. You can delete or re-create it whenever you want.

> Any good resources or knowledge you want to share about Logic Apps /
> Function Apps being dependent on other resource types?

One thing I want to remind. Please keep your resources in the same region if you dont have some special requirement. This is not only because of some built-in restrictions, but it can also help you save costs. (For resources in Azure, data transmission between resources located in different regions requires additional bandwidth fees.)

Comment: Thank you. To your last paragraph-- Is there a way to change Logic/Function apps to a new region? Some of my apps are in different regions (West, Central, etc.). 

And question, what about "App Service Plan" resource? Can we change all Function and Logic Apps in a Resource Group to use one App Service plan? Thanks again. These images and answers were extremely helpful.

Comment: @Caroline 1, No. If apps is already created, then it is impossible to change a new region. 2, Yes. Basically, a plan is a way to allocate computing resources, so you can use the same plan as long as the rules are met.